# How to match two columns in csv?

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files. One contains City, Lat,  Long and the other one has City pairs i.e. City1, City2. I have to calculate the distance between these city pairs.

City_pair.csv  1st csv file

```
City1,City2
Mumbai,Bengaluru
Delhi,Mumbai
Bengaluru,Delhi
```

Lat_long.csv 2nd csv file

```
City,Lat,Long
Mumbai,19.1195,72.8469
Bengaluru,13.0046,77.6351
Delhi,28.714,77.1673
```

For this I have to pick up the lat long of each city from the lat_long.csv file for each occurrence of it in the city_pair.csv and then feed it into osrm api.

Right now I'm unable to pick up the lat long corresponding to the city. Here's what I've tried:

```
def distance():
global latitude1,latitude2,longitude1,longitude2
with open('city_pair.csv') as fin1,\
     open('lat_long.csv') as fin2:

    reader1 = DictReader(fin1)
    reader2 = DictReader(fin2)

    for line2 in reader2:
        outline = dict(line2)
        fin1.seek(0) # resets the reader1 iterator
        for line1 in reader1:
            if line1['City1'] in line2['City'].lower():
                latitude1 = line2['Lat']
                longitude1 = line2['Long']
                orig_coord= latitude1, longitude1
            if line1['City2'] in line2['City'].lower():
                latitude2 = line2['Lat']
                longitude2 = line2['Long']
                dest_coord = latitude2, longitude2
            print latitude1,longitude1        
            url = "http://localhost:5000/viaroute?loc="+str(latitude1)+","+str(longitude1)+"&loc="+str(latitude2)+","+str(longitude2)
            result= simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
            driving_time = result['route_summary']['total_time']
            driving_distance = result['route_summary']['total_distance']
            print "Distance between"+line1['City1']+"to"+line1['City2']+ " = "+driving_distance
            print "Travel Time between"+line1['City1']+"to"+line1['City2']+ " = "+driving_time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would just go through the lat_long.csv once and dump all the data into a dict first. then you would be able to access it much quicker and easier.

note that your current solution is ugly and O(n^2) vs dumping to dict and then accessing the has table to get lats and longs is only O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get all the cities lat & long into a dictionary then use your code to calculate the distance between the cities.

```
import csv

with open('lat_long.csv', 'rb') as src_file:
csv_file = csv.reader(src_file)
lat_long_dict = {}
for row in csv_file:
    lat_long_dict[row[0]] = [row[1], row[2]]
```